# IIS website not created for new web application in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

When creating a new web application in Central Administration in SharePoint 2010 Foundation, the web application was created but the IIS website was not created for that web application and shows this message:

> The Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web application has been created. If this is the first time that you have used this application pool with a SharePoint Web application, you must wait until the Internet Information Services (IIS) Web site has been created on all servers. By default, no new SharePoint site collections are created with the Web application. If you have just created a Forms Based Authentication (FBA) Web application, then before creating a new site collection, you will need to perform some additional configuration steps. Learn about how to configure a Web application for FBA. Once you are finished, to create a new site collection, go to the Create Site Collection page

If I go to create a site collection for this web application it doesn't work.

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things to check,

- if SharePoint Timer and Admin services running on all servers
- make sure the SharePoint Foundation Web Application services running on your WFE
- when you trying to create new site collection, when error you get?
- try to reset IIS on the server and then check.
- share the screen print or error logs if any.

Comment: I solved the issue buddy,                                        SOLUTION : Create Your web application with administrator or default SharePoint administrator it works fine now....
This problem was created due to Login access so check that first.
Thanks